# How can I convert video and audio files into iPod/iPad playable formats?

Tags: ipad, video, file-conversion, switching

I am quite a non-technical guy when it comes to such stuff and hence looking for "easy" solutions.

On Windows, I had used Red Kawa Videora to convert the various audio and video formats to iPod-playable formats. I think it also has a version which works on Mac.

I would like to know if there is other (possibly better and as much or more user-friendly) software which does the above job of converting various audio and video formats into what Apple products can play. (I guess what works on iPod also works on iPad.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HandBrake used to be my go-to app for this task but lets face it: nightmare UI. Especially if you're a professed "non-technical guy".

The new wonder-in-a-box video convert is [Smart Converter](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/smart-converter/id447513724?mt=12). Like HandBrake, it's free. Unlike HandBrake the UI is very non-threatening. Drop file, pick output format, go. Works for video and audio.

Comment: Wow, thanks Ian, I've never heard of this app but I will give it a try! :)

Comment: @TheNumb it is relatively new, at least on the App Store.

Comment: @Ian C. Thanks for the reference. To download it from the appstore I seem to need an Apple Id. Can I have multiple Apple Ids? Like from two different email ids?                 Also some of the reviews of this app tells me that this can't convert .avi files..Is that true?

Comment: @Anirbit: I don't know about multiple Apple IDs. Maybe ask that as a separate question. It hasn't failed to convert anything I've thrown at it yet. Doesn't mean it's infallible though.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

[Switch](http://www.nch.com.au/switch/index.html) is what I use for ***all*** my audio conversions. Although it says you need to pay for it, there is a free version. It may seem somewhat confusing, but it's free. As Ian C. said, Handbrake is the **best** video conversion software. (because it's free!!!)